# How do I remove a Wi-Fi sync with a laptop that I no longer have in my possession?

Tags: itunes, ipad

I have a first generation iPad with many documents in iBooks. This iPad is still synchronized with a laptop that is no longer in my possession. This means I can't sync to my new laptop over Wi-Fi. How do I remove the Wi-Fi sync connection to my old laptop?

Comment: I've only been able to cut the umbilical cord using a full restore of the unit.  Probably not what you want.  Perhaps a backup in itunes first can then be restored after the brainwash.

Comment: An edit might help people to help you - Do you not know how to go through the steps to sync the device or are you worried about the prompt that warns you that the existing content will be deleted?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen and bmike - I have already synced by device with my computer and made a backup. All the apps are in the backup and synced. But in the backup the content of I books is not in here. As you write bmike Iam worried about the warning. If all the existing content is deleted, I have no backup any more. So therefore I am carefull. Who knows the answer what to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you're only worried about losing items purchased through iTunes on the Apple ID you're currently using, like iBooks, then this will work:

1. Make sure you're logged into iTunes with your Apple ID. (The one you made all of your purchases with.)
2. Sync the iPad to your new computer. Yes, the existing content will be deleted.
3. From within iTunes, navigate to the iTunes Store. In a column to the right, you will see a link (under the heading, "Quick Links" that says, "Purchased." Click on that link.
4. The new store page that will be displayed is broken down into sections, which you'll see across the top (Music, Movies, TV Shows, Apps, Books). You should be able to re-download any content you previously purchased, including books. I just tested this by deleting a book I previously purchased, and I was able to re-download it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Even without syncing you can get the music, apps, and books which you bought via iTunes to the computer:

1. Visit the iTunes Store with the Apple ID you used for buying the books.
2. In the menu on the right-hand side, you can find an entry **Purchased**. Depending on the store, this might be in a different language. You can first visit the US store, figure out where the menu entry is, and then switch back to your store and look for the same entry in your language.
3. Click the **Purchased** entry. This will bring you to a page where you can find the music, apps, and books you bought via iTunes.
4. Click the cloud symbol to re-download items to the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > General > Reset, and then Reset All Settings

This seems a very poor method of resolution, and a code bug, IMO.